# Where are Tomcat application log files stored in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: tomcat, logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Where does Elastic Beanstalk store log output from Tomcat on each EC2 instance?

I've configured SSH and want to tail the log file, but don't know where it's located.

Comment: Simplest way to find out: in beanstalk console (AWS management website), go to `Logs`, click `Snapshot Logs`, and the resulting log snapshot will contain the path to all the relevant log files on that machine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something seems to have changed a bit on this, as I have a new Elastic Beanstalk application where the logs are located in:

```
/var/log/tomcat7/
```

Note that the easiest way to view stuff in here is to `sudo su` first, as this directory is owned by root. Whereas, I have an older instance where the logs are in:

```
/opt/tomcat7/logs/
```

I'm not sure why there is a disparity in this, as both applications use the tomcat7 container, but this seems to be the state of things to date.

Comment: The location was changed in one of the late 2012 AMI updates.

Answer (score 6):

By default, AWS Elastic Beanstalk log output from Tomcat is written to `/opt/tomcat7/logs/tail_catalina.out`. (depends on Tomcat version)

These log messages are written by `java.util.logging` configured in Tomcat from `/opt/tomcat7/conf`.

edit: this was changed in late 2012 and now applies only to "Legacy" containers.

Comment: There is no folder by the name of `tomcat7` in `/opt` directory of my ec2 instance.

Comment: it depends on the Tomcat version. Maybe you're running Tomcat 6?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at an Elastic Beanstalk instance? You should also see an `elasticbeanstalk` directory in `/opt`.

Comment: I realized that I am running on Amazon EC2 and not Elastic beanstalk both must have different folder structure. Sorry for trouble.

Comment: /var/log/tomcat7 seems to be the current location (I just created a new Elastic Beanstalk app)

Comment: see answer from Paul Sanwald

Answer (score 4):

if you are working on Tomcat7 the you can ind your log at

***/var/log/tomcat7***

if you are working on tomcat8 then you can find here

***/var/log/tomcat8***

Answer (score 3):

as of March 10, 2014, Tomcat 7 versions of Beanstalk log to /var/log/httpd for Apache and /var/log/tomcat7 for Tomcat logs.

```
-rw-rw---- 1 tomcat tomcat 12444 Mar 10 18:28 catalina.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 13664 Mar 10 18:28 localhost_access_log.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat     0 Feb  6 16:42 tomcat7-initd.log
```

Answer (score 1):

They are stored in S3 server under the bucket name **elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1(region name)-(appno).**.

Logs are stored in folders that are organized based on the **beanstalk environment name** and the directory name would be the **ec2-instance's id**, that generated the tomcat logs.

Comment: this is the location to which the log files are rolled, not the location on the actual instances

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Catalina log

```
cd /usr/local/apache-tomcat7/logs 
tail -f Catalina.out
```